# MySQL : AVG of AVG impossible?

Tags: mysql, request, average

I want to do an average : the problem is for 1 item i'm calculating the AVG of each elements (**working**) but as soon as i want the GLOBAL average of the averages of the categories (something and foo) it doesn't work (mysql throw me an error : see the syntax i used just below).

I need to do that because i want to sort the result by the global average

```
SELECT AVG(AVG(category1)+AVG(category2)) /2 as moy
..... 
ORDER BY moy DESC
```

Thanks,

edit : I would like to have the average of averages of each category
edit 2 :

got table : server (...)
got table : answer_poll (price, interface, services, quality)

a user's got 1 server, and he can answer to a poll for this server severall times

```
 SELECT s.name , s.type , COUNT(s.GSP_nom) as nb_votes, 
 TRUNCATE(AVG(quality), 2) as quality,  TRUNCATE(AVG(price), 2)  as price,    
 TRUNCATE(AVG(interface), 2)  as interface,  TRUNCATE(AVG(services), 2)  as services
  FROM answer_poll AS v
  INNER JOIN server AS s ON v.idServ = s.idServ
  GROUP BY s.name
ORDER BY global average :d
```

This request = the average for each category, but i want the average of the averages :p

Comment: Define "It doesn't work." The average of the averages, and the average of all of the items, are *not* the same two numbers.

Comment: yeah, i want the average of the averages ;)

Comment: Sometimes temp tables work wonders.

Comment: @Romain Hippeau ,what does that means ?

Comment: You create a temp table, store some intermediate queries into there and then run additional queries from those temporary tables.

Comment: Isn't the average of the averages the same as simply the overall average ?

Comment: Maybe if you show us a sample table, reduced to simply be relevant to this problem and the query you have as well as the results you are seeing, we could help you better.

Comment: i've updated the question to add more details as you asked ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be that?:

```
SELECT AVG(avg_) as superavg
FROM (
    SELECT category, AVG(val) as avg_
    FROM foo_table
    GROUP BY category
) as avgs;
```

Comment: i'll try that ASAP and i'll let you know

Comment: +1: Correct - you can not use an aggregate on another, you have to reference the column from a derived table/inline view/subselect.