# Nested average group by function mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my `reviews` table: It's a table for generic reviews for a location with mostly ratings.

```
    +---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | reviewid      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | createdate    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | locid         | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
    | clubid        | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | userid        | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
    | legacyuser    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | author        | varchar(100)  | YES  |     |         |                |
    | comment       | varchar(4000) | YES  |     |         |                |
    | rating        | double        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | status        | int(11)       | YES  |     | 1       |                |
    | likes         | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | dislikes      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | spotlight     | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | dancerquality | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | pvtdancevalue | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | hospitality   | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | dancerratio   | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | dancervariety | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | covervalue    | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | drinksvalue   | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | foodvalue     | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | atmosphere    | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | soundsystem   | double        | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | rebuttal      | varchar(5000) | YES  |     |         |                |
    +---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If you look, you'll see these 3 columns that are important here:

- covervalue (the cover price rating for this review)
- drinksvalue (the drinks price rating for this review)
- foodvalue (the food price rating for this review)

Here's what I need:

average of (avg of covervalue + avg of drinksvalue + avg of foodvalue)

My assumption is that the average of averages will give me the overall best value for pricing.

Here is my current query:

```
select avg(avg(foodvalue)+avg(drinksvalue)+avg(covervalue)) as avg from reviews where locid=3166;
```

Here is the response `ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function`

This clearly is not working or else I'd not be on here. Not quite sure how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2799343/3294262

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL : AVG of AVG impossible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798355/mysql-avg-of-avg-impossible)

Comment: Also if you take a look at common [average definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average) I think you can find a way to calculate your average without using avg(avg)...